# How to authenticate players via GameCenter

Tags: ios, game-center

I need to authenticate players via game center. I managed to do it, however it stopped working. Now I always get "viewController = nil" and when checking if the localPlayer is authenticated it always returns false.

This is what I'm doing:

```
-(void)authenticateLocalPlayer{
    GKLocalPlayer *localPlayer = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];

    localPlayer.authenticateHandler = ^(UIViewController *viewController, NSError *error){
        if (viewController != nil) {
            [_spriteViewController presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
        } else {
            if ([GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].authenticated) {
                NSLog(@"authenticated");
                _gameCenterEnabled = YES;

                // Get the default leaderboard identifier.
                [[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer] loadDefaultLeaderboardIdentifierWithCompletionHandler:^(NSString *leaderboardIdentifier, NSError *error) {

                    if (error != nil) {
                        NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
                    } else {
                        _leaderboardIdentifier = leaderboardIdentifier;
                    }
                }];
            } else {
                NSLog(@"not authenticated"); // This is always triggered
                _gameCenterEnabled = NO;
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? What things should I do/check first for this to work?

Comment: Did you read a discussion here? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKLocalPlayer_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/GKLocalPlayer/authenticateHandler ? You should present the view controller passed to your handler to let the player authenticate via Game Center

Comment: I'm not sure why it wasn't being presented. I just corrected it but a lot of times the viewController is nil. Why may this be happening?

Comment: Did you check you are calling all this on the main thread?

Comment: yes, on startup I always get "not authenticated"

Comment: @lisovaccaro - can you clear up Game Center login by going inside Game Center app once and try from your game again? Sometimes it just sticks to the previous session and discards changes made by you.

Comment: The problem had to do with the test device which was running iOS8.

Comment: check https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5930220 . it saying if you tried multiple time failure of game center then we have to reset all setting of our phone. then it works. I have experieced of this.

Comment: Did you seen a beautiful Example on this Link - http://www.appcoda.com/ios-game-kit-framework/       .Very good step by step explanation.

Answer (score 0):

if you have tested multiple time in same device then first of all reset your phone setting. Refer [this link](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5930220)

then this code helps you.

```
       if ([GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].authenticated == NO) {
            GKLocalPlayer* localPlayer = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];

            localPlayer.authenticateHandler = ^(UIViewController *gcvc,NSError *error) {

                if(gcvc) {

                    [self presentViewController:gcvc animated:YES completion:nil];
                }
                else {
                    _gameCenterEnabled = NO;

                }
            };
        }

        else if ([GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].authenticated == YES){
            _gameCenterEnabled = YES;


        }
```

And for leaderboard identifier you can define statically first in code which you have already taken from itunes. It works fine. But before this reset all setting which is necessary for game center as if multiple time game center authentication fails then game center disable for that app. We must have to reset all setting. If you want to try then try in iphone simulator. reset iphone simulator and run this code. It works.